# Field has an incomplete type: int*[]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, types, dynamic-arrays

```
class NumberArray {

int *nums []; // this line gets error for incomplete type int *[]
int size_;

public:
    NumberArray(const int i){nums = new int[i]; size_ = i;}
    ~NumberArray(){delete [] *nums;}

    void set(int i, int n){(*nums)[i] = n;}
    int get(int i){return (*nums)[i];}
    int min();
    int max();
    double avg();
};
```

I realize this is something really simple and I'm missing it.  Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the type system, a dynamically sized array is more or less equivalent to a pointer to the first element. That's how you use it in the constructor too.

Change the declaration to:

```
int *nums;
```

Then there's the best practice of not using plain arrays at all, but instead use `std::vector` which provides better and safer operations.

Comment: You get answer in 7min.  Thanks dude.  Once I stop studying the easy stuff and move on to data structures that are actually useful, stuff like this leaves my brain.

Comment: @jboulter11 the "easy" stuff actually isn't that easy. I would say it is best ignored until you have to implement some expert stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Of course the line gets an error, you need to specify a size for the array. If you don't want to specify a size, then use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

In this case you don't want the `[]` at all, since you use `nums` as a plain dynamic array allocated on the heap. Instead you try to declare it as an (empty) array of pointers, and the use dereferencing when accessing it which will not work very well.

Unless you are required to use pointers and `new`/`delete`, then you should definitely use `std::vector` (in the future, whenever you hear or see the words "dynamic" and "array" in the same sentence, you should first of all think of `std::vector`). Otherwise declare it as just a simple pointer, e.g.

```
int* nums;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the array has no size. You don't need the `[]`, and when accessing the element, you don't need `*`, either:

```
class NumberArray {

int *nums;   //<---
int size_;

public:
    NumberArray(const int i){nums = new int[i]; size_ = i;}
    ~NumberArray(){delete [] nums;}       //<---

    void set(int i, int n){nums[i] = n;}  //<---
    int get(int i){return nums[i];}       //<---
    int min();
    int max();
    double avg();
};
```

`std::vector` is usually a better choice, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Make `nums` a simple pointer. Then your code could look like this:

```
class NumberArray {

int *nums; 
int size_;

public:
    NumberArray(const int i) : size_(i) { nums = new int[i]; }
    ~NumberArray(){ delete[] nums; }

    void set(int i, int n){ nums[i] = n; }
    int get(int i){ return nums[i]; }
    ...
};
```

And although this class wraps dynamically allocated array and takes advantage of RAII, it would be still more reasonable to use `std::vector` instead C-style array (unless you can't use vector for some reason).